# Unable to iterate and compare two lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have the following models:

```
public class ProductRequest
{
    public List<string> Skus { get; set; }
}

public class ProductResponse
{
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
}
```

The code below is part of a method that receives an input parameter of `ProductRequest request` and executes a LINQ query. I want to to check if any `sku` from the original list is missing from the results list, but I am unable to come up with the proper syntax. It does not like the line `!costs.Contains(sku)`. Not sure what I am doing wrong?

```
List<ProductResponse> costs = (from x in this.SkuManager.GetSkusBySkuNumber(request.Skus.ToList())
                                            select new ProductCostResponse
                                            {
                                                Sku = x.Sku,
                                                Cost = x.Cost
                                            }).ToList();

foreach (var sku in request.Skus)
{
    if (!costs.Contains(sku))
    {
        //some error handling here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `.Any` instead of `.Contains`?

Comment: `Costs` can't contain a `Sku`.  `Sku` is of type `string` and  each `cost` in `costs` is a `ProductResponse` object.  You need to iterate through costs or otherwise access the 'ProductResponse.Sku' property to make your comparison.

Comment: `HashSet<string> costSkus = new HashSet<string>(costs.Select(c => c.Sku));` and then check `!costSkus.Contains(sku)`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're checking for **any** then you may want to use the `.Any` method.

```
foreach (var sku in request.Skus)
{
    if (!costs.Any(x => x.Sku == sku))
    {
        //some error handling here...
    }
}
```

Or you could use [`.Exists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
foreach (var sku in request.Skus)
{
    if (!costs.Exists(x => x.Sku == sku))
    {
        //some error handling here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
!costs.Any(x=>x.Sku == sku)
```

or even better

```
costs.All(x=>x.Sku != sku)
```

Comment: better in what sense?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad  looks for me compacter and describes logic better